# image / document scanner source selection changing

Tags: windows-7, windows, scanner, scanning, multi-function-printer

I have an issue which might seem strange. In a computer two scanners are installed. A flatbed scanner and a document feeder. We use some web based procedures to do things in which document scanning is required.

Now my **`ISSUE`**: in the online document scanning application, I want it to scan using one scanner or the other scanner.

The only way currently I'm forcing it to change the scanner source is by installing Corel Photo Shop Pro with a trail settings, and go to File Menu -> Import -> Select Twain Source and select the different scanner from there.

That is not the permanent solution. For a few days it worked, but now I have to select the different scanner after every restart of the computer and the change is not getting permanent.

#### QUESTIONS

- Can any one tell me how to change the scanner source without using that software?
- Also how to do it if required to frequently change it between the scanners?
- How can I make these changes permanent?

Comment: The online document scanning application should include the feature of switching scanners. Did you develop the app yourself or you use an off-the-shelf solution? If the prior, you may update the code to add the feature or you may contact the vendor of your document scanning app.

Comment: not developed by me. but i think if i can do with oracle, I should be able to have some softwares which should do the same too.